# Embedding of $U(n)$ in $SO(2n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I want to study the embedding of $U(n)$ in $SO(2n)$. I write $Z=X+iY\in U(n)$ and use the realification map

\begin{align*}
\varphi:C^n\rightarrow R^{2n}:X+iY\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
X &-Y\\
Y & X
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

I note that

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
X & -Y\\
Y & X
\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}
X & -Y\\
Y & X
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
X^TX+Y^TY & -X^TY+Y^TX\\
-Y^TX+X^TY & Y^TY+X^TX
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

since $Z^*Z=(X^T-iY^T)(X+iY)=X^TX+iX^TY-iY^TX+Y^TY=I$.

My question is: how to determine the orthogonal projection operator $\pi$ of any $A\in R^{2n\times 2n}$ on the tangent space of $\varphi U(n)$ at $\varphi Z$?

Attempt: I note that any element of the tangent space of $\varphi U(n)$ at $\varphi Z$ must be on the form

\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B\\
B & A
\end{bmatrix}

and must satisfy $A^TX+X^TA+B^TY+Y^TB=0$ and $-A^TY+X^TB+B^TX+Y^TA=0$. The last relations are from the time derivatives of the matrix equations above. I am stuck here. How to orthogonally project an arbitrary matrix on

\begin{align}
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B\\
B & A
\end{bmatrix}\in R^{2n\times 2n}\,|\, A^TX+X^TA+B^TY+Y^TB=0,-A^TY+X^TB+B^TX+Y^TA=0\right\}?
\end{align}

Comment: related math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763517/embedding-the-full-un-subset-spin2n, you know the answer?